# Cowboy - REST callback isn't called

Tags: rest, erlang, cowboy

I'm trying to implement Rest handler and have next code:

```
-module(example_handler).
-behaviour(cowboy_handler).

-export([init/2,
         allowed_methods/2,
         content_types_provided/2,
         get_json/2]).

init(Req, State) ->
    {cowboy_rest, Req, State}.

allowed_methods(Req, State) ->
    io:format("allowed_methods~n"),
    {[<<"GET">>, <<"POST">>], Req, State}.

content_types_provided(Req, State) ->
    io:format("content_types_provided~n"),
    {[{{<<"application">>, <<"json">>, []}, get_json}], Req, State}.

get_json(_Req, _State) ->
    io:format("get_json~n")
```

Then when I try to send request with curl like that:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/xxx/xx
```

I get next output:

```
allowed_methods
content_types_provided
```

get_json() is not called! But when I use GET method everything looks ok:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:8080/xxx/xx
----------------------------------------------------------------------
allowed_methods
content_types_provided
get_json
```

What I missed?

Comment: It would be nice if you start doing something on your own, and when you get stuck on something, ask about it in particular.

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ I changed my question, could you please answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

`content_types_provided` is not the same as `content_types_accepted`; since you are handling a `POST` you need the later.

---

In [Cowboy](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.0/manual/cowboy_rest/) `2.0.0`, which is what I use, `content_types_provided` callback return the list of media types the resource provides in order of preference. So, when you use:

```
content_types_provided(Req, State) ->
  {[
    {{<<"application">>, <<"json">>, []}, get_json}
  ], Req, State}.
```

You are basically telling Cowboy that, from now on, this *handler* supports JSON responses. That's why when you do a `GET` you will successfully get an `HTTP 200 (OK)`...but a `POST` doesn't work.

On the other hand, the `content_types_accepted` callback allow to state what `content-types` to accept. You are indeed allowed to send `POST` requests since you added `<<"POST">>` in the `allowed_methods` callback but that will result in an `HTTP 415 (Unsupported Media Type)` response because **you haven't told `cowboy_rest` that you want to accept `application/json`**.

This is something that should work for you:

```
-module(example_handler).

-export([init/2]).

-export([
  allowed_methods/2,
  content_types_accepted/2,
  content_types_provided/2
]).

-export([get_json/2, post_json/2]).

%%%==============================================
%%% Exports
%%%==============================================
init(Req, Opts) ->
  {cowboy_rest, Req, Opts}.

allowed_methods(Req, State) ->
  lager:debug("allowed_methods"),
  {[<<"GET">>, <<"POST">>], Req, State}.

content_types_accepted(Req, State) ->
  lager:debug("content_types_accepted"),
  {[
    {{<<"application">>, <<"json">>, []}, post_json}
  ], Req, State}.

content_types_provided(Req, State) ->
  lager:debug("content_types_provided"),
  {[
    {{<<"application">>, <<"json">>, []}, get_json}
  ], Req, State}.

get_json(Req, State) ->
  lager:debug("get_json"),
  {<<"{ \"hello\": \"there\" }">>, Req, State}.

post_json(Req, State) ->
  lager:debug("post_json"),
  {true, Req, State}.

%%%==============================================
%%% Internal
%%%==============================================
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is logical, shame to me ... I'm new to Erlang but passionate by it.